# where or how to see if data is still being transferred over usb to mass storage

Tags: usb-drive, io, file-transfer

The data transfer to my mp3 player is very slow via USB connection.

I have a mp3-player from Samsung (YP-M1JCB/EDC) which I have connected to my Fedora linux (the *pc connection* in the mp3 player is set to MSC, i.e. mass storage device class).

When I connect the mp3 player to my computer with a usb cable, with `dmesg` I see this:

```
[1351555.669080] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[1351555.812993] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=5123
[1351555.813047] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[1351555.813059] usb 2-2: Product: YP-M1
[1351555.813065] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Samsung Electronics
[1351555.813071] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: b37c03ac0f1647c2a9720aae4e913080
[1351555.896394] scsi47 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[1351556.899771] scsi 47:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Samsung  YP-M1            1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[1351556.900481] scsi 47:0:0:1: Direct-Access     Samsung  microSD          1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
[1351556.902422] sd 47:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[1351556.904403] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] 1896703 4096-byte logical blocks: (7.76 GB/7.23 GiB)
[1351556.904617] sd 47:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[1351556.904922] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[1351556.904930] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 00 06 00 00
[1351556.907342] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[1351556.907361] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1351556.910613] sd 47:0:0:1: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[1351556.911467] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] 1896703 4096-byte logical blocks: (7.76 GB/7.23 GiB)
[1351556.912448] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[1351556.912457] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1351556.913372]  sdc: sdc1
[1351556.916978] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] 1896703 4096-byte logical blocks: (7.76 GB/7.23 GiB)
[1351556.919093] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] Asking for cache data failed
[1351556.919111] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[1351556.919120] sd 47:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

**Seems ok to me.**
I then mount the device `/dev/sdc1`:

```
sudo mount -o uid=erik /dev/sdc1 /mnt/usb-stick/
```

When I create a small text file on the device, and then unmount it, there seems to be no problem. I can read the text file on the device (it has a text reading app).

But when I copy some bigger files (mp3 files) to the device, it takes forever. Well, the command line

```
cp supermusic.mp3 /mnt/usb-stick/Music/
```

finishes after a few seconds. But when I try to unmount the device, it never finishes. `dmesg` shows:

```
[1352056.822086] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352087.878103] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352118.854062] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352149.830105] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352180.870081] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352211.846060] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352211.969584] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[1352211.969601] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[1352211.969607] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1352211.969612] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[1352211.969617] Write(10): 2a 00 00 1b 51 02 00 00 1e 00
[1352211.969634] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 14321680
[1352242.822056] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352273.862064] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352304.838066] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352335.814100] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352366.854074] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352397.830096] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352397.954124] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[1352397.954141] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[1352397.954147] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1352397.954153] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[1352397.954157] Write(10): 2a 00 00 1b 51 20 00 00 1e 00
[1352397.954174] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 14321920
[1352428.870469] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352459.846068] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352490.822088] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352521.862078] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352552.838052] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352583.878077] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352584.005386] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[1352584.005401] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[1352584.005407] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1352584.005413] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[1352584.005417] Write(10): 2a 00 00 1b 51 3e 00 00 1e 00
[1352584.005434] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 14322160
[1352614.854055] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352628.359667] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 46
[1352645.830068] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352676.870073] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352707.846090] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352738.822066] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352769.862077] usb 2-2: reset high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[1352769.985579] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc] Unhandled error code
[1352769.985596] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc]  
[1352769.985601] Result: hostbyte=DID_ABORT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1352769.985608] sd 48:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: 
[1352769.985611] Write(10): 2a 00 00 1b 51 5c 00 00 1e 00
[1352769.985630] end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 14322400
```

There seem to be some problems, but why? I have connected many other mass storage devices and never had a problem.

How to see if data is still transferred? And how fast? If I go to /mnt/usb-stick/Music the file seems to be there already (full size).

PS: When I just remove the USB cable after waiting very long time, when I reconnect it and start fsck.vfat on the partition it finds a loooot of errors with chinese glyphs which takes a very long time to fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USB connection resets indicate that there is something physically wrong with your USB device (or maybe the electrical connection).  The fact that other drives do not exhibit the problem supports this theory.

The logs confirm this. (“end_request: I/O error, dev sdc, …”, etc.)

Discard it or do not use it for important things anymore.

Comment: Ok, I’ll try it with bluetooth then (even slower!!!).

Comment: Yes, that will be less error-prone.  Depending on the device (like smartphone to computer), `ftp` or `samba` within the local (WiFi) network might also work (e.g. with the ES File Explorer app), though it takes a little time to set up on both ends.

Comment: Bluetooth was to slow. And wifi isn’t available for this device (mp3 player). So I ended up copying the files to a micro sd card on another phone (cause I have no micro sd card reader) and then putting the filled micro sd card into the mp3 player. A bit complicated, but it works and is much faster than bluetooth and always works.